# Can you convert string.split array into JButtons

Tags: java, swing, split, jbutton

I want to make it so that it will make buttons
eg if the txt file is : * * * * * *
it will remove the spaces to *****
and then put each * into its own button

```
        //loads file and removes the spaces and stores it in an array
        public static void loadFile(JButton[][] board, String fileName) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader inputStream = null;

    try {
        inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        String lineRead = inputStream.readLine();
        while (lineRead != null) {
            String[] splited = lineRead.split(" ");
            for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++){
                board[i] = lineRead.split(" ");
            }
    System.out.print(lineRead);
        } 
            lineRead = inputStream.readLine();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
        System.out.println("Error opening file");
    }
    finally {       
        if (inputStream != null)
            inputStream.close();
    }
}
//a button that opens the fileselector and then calls the loadfile method
JButton file1 = new JButton("Player File");
    file1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        JFileChooser open = new JFileChooser();
        open.showOpenDialog(null);
        loadFile(buttonPlayer, "CPU.txt");

        }   
    });
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the snippet you provided? Does it fail with an exception? Produce the wrong result?

Comment: it just says jbutton[] cannot be converted to string[]

Comment: you should change line `board[i] = lineRead.split(" ");` with this line `board[i] = new JButton(lineRead[i]);`

Answer (score 1):

Try Something like this :-

```
 JButton jButton;
    String yourText=" * * * * * ";
    String btnNames[]=yourText.split(" ");
    System.out.println(yourText);
    for(String btnName:btnNames){
        System.out.print(btnName);
        jButton=new JButton();
        jButton.setName(btnName.trim());

        // ......you can put your other stuff here......
    }
```

Comment: You would use setText(), not setName() to add the "*" to the button.

Comment: yes that is good but to make different button we need to give name also. so we can retrieve button by using that names.

Comment: No you don't need to give the button a name. In any case this wouldn't work if you give the button the same name.